# How can i get token number from notify url in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, sandbox

I am using citruspay Payment gateway in my project, when return url hit the page

than  TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53: error show.

How can i match token .

route.php

```
Route::POST('ideas/paymentResponse',function(){
    return View::make('ideas.paymentDone');
});
```

payment.php

```
 <form  method="post" action="https://sandbox.citruspay.com/qwer">

         <input type="hidden" id="merchantTxnId" name="merchantTxnId" value="<?php echo $merchantTxnId; ?>" />

         <input type="hidden" id="orderAmount" name="orderAmount" value="<?php echo $orderAmount; ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

         <input type="hidden" id="currency" name="currency" value="<?php $currency ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="http://local.ideabazaar.com/ideas/paymentResponse" />
         <input type="hidden" id="notifyUrl" name="notifyUrl" value="http://local.ideabazaar.com/ideas/paidNotify" />
         <input type="hidden" id="secSignature" name="secSignature" value="<?php echo $securitySignature ?>" />
         <input type="Submit" class="redBtn" value="Pay Now"/>
```

paymentResponse.php

```
@extends('layouts.home')
@section('content')

   <?php
    set_include_path('../lib'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
    //Replace this with your secret key from the citrus panel
    $secret_key = "***************";
{{ csrf_token() }}
    $data = "";
    $flag = "true";
    if(isset($_POST['TxId'])) {
        $txnid = $_POST['TxId'];
        $data .= $txnid;
    }
     if(isset($_POST['TxStatus'])) {
        $txnstatus = $_POST['TxStatus'];
        $data .= $txnstatus;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['amount'])) {
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $data .= $amount;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['pgTxnNo'])) {
        $pgtxnno = $_POST['pgTxnNo'];
        $data .= $pgtxnno;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['issuerRefNo'])) {
        $issuerrefno = $_POST['issuerRefNo'];
        $data .= $issuerrefno;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['authIdCode'])) {
        $authidcode = $_POST['authIdCode'];
        $data .= $authidcode;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $data .= $firstName;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['lastName'])) {
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
        $data .= $lastName;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['pgRespCode'])) {
        $pgrespcode = $_POST['pgRespCode'];
        $data .= $pgrespcode;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['addressZip'])) {
        $pincode = $_POST['addressZip'];
        $data .= $pincode;
     }
     if(isset($_POST['signature'])) {
        $signature = $_POST['signature'];
     }

         $respSignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret_key);
     if($signature != "" && strcmp($signature, $respSignature) != 0) {
        $flag = "false";
     }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;CHARSET=iso-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        if ($flag == "true") {  
        ?>
        Your Unique Transaction/Order Id : <?php echo $txnid ?>
        Transaction Status : <?php echo $txnstatus ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        Citrus Response Signature and Our (Merchant) Signature Mis-Mactch 
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
    </html>

@stop
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your payment gateway allows to specify a custom callback URL per request you could set the callback URL to include the current CSFR token. Something like this:

```
$callbackUrl = url('ideas/paymentResponse?_token=' . csrf_token());
```

If you can't customize the callback URL per request, the only option you have left is [disabling CSFR protection for your callback URL](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-excluding-uris). Something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
    * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $except = [
        'ideas/paymentResponse',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Javi. I skip the  csrf token  particular  route.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a hidden input with the _token and later get that value as you do to get the other form fields in your ajax post.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

On your view you can set an object with the _token

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _globalObj = {{ json_encode(array('_token'=> csrf_token())) }}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Rahautos.But my response come from payment gateway site, than how i can  match session token and post token?